# LAMP server: cannot view the created website

Tags: 12.04, lamp

I'm new to Linux, and only use it for surfing web until recently.

For everyone to know, I had developed a website complete with its database using WampServer on windows. And I created the all the pages using adobe dreamweaver. The site had been working perfectly.

Recently, I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my machine (dual boot with the prior windows) together with LAMP server, and I was intending to transfer my whole website pages and databases to the ubuntu platform. The LAMP server seems to be working fine.

After that I copied all the .php website files from WampServer to LAMP in the directory /var/www But when I tried to view the page through mozilla browser, it only showed blank white page, although the url showed the correct address.

Why was this happen?
Did I do anything wrong during LAMP installation?
The site was designed with css style, would this contribute to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you given www-data an access to the files you copied in /var/www/?

> $ sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/Your_Site/

or you let www-data own your site folder

> $ sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/Your_Site/

Comment: I put the index.php file and all other files under the /var/www/ directory, do I need to sudo chmod -R 755 each .php file?

Comment: Giving `755` permission for everything is not good. there is a big security issue :)

Comment: @realfalah No!! for `php` configuration files you should give 644 `sudo chmod -R 644 each .php`

Comment: No you don't have to do that in every file. -R already do that recursively. So all files under your directory will be set with 755 permission.

Comment: Thak you everyone! It worked!

Comment: @realfalah glad the problem is solved. Please accept One of the answers. It helps  others :)